# Can Hungary stop the EC from cutting Poland's subsidies?

Tags: european-union, poland, subsidies, european-commission

European Commission has [recently issued](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2022/02/08/brussels-to-withhold-eu-funds-from-poland-to-cover-unpaid-fines) that it will subtract the fines for Poland from its subsidies. Is this the kind of decision that needs an approval of all the other member states prime ministers (a unanimous European council vote)? Or is there perhaps another way Hungary could intervene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Hungary cannot intervene unilaterally. However, a decision by the European Commission could cancel the penalty payments or cap them at a certain amount.

The fine was imposed in accordance with Article 260 of the TFEU, which grants the European Court of Justice the power to fine and impose penalty payments on member states. The ECJ made the following [order](https://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf;jsessionid=899BD782236E0F430A78B38ABB37BCB2?text=&docid=246301&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=4551505) on September 20th, 2021:

> The Republic of Poland is ordered to pay the European Commission a
> penalty payment of EUR 500 000 per day, from the date of notification
> of the present order to the Republic of Poland until that Member State
> complies with the order of the Vice-President of the Court of 21 May
> 2021.

The ability to subtract these penalty payments from EU subsidies was delegated to the accounting officer of the Commission, currently [Maria Rosa Aldea Busquets](https://ec.europa.eu/info/persons/maria-rosa-aldea-busquets_en), in [Commission Decision C(2018)5119](https://ec.europa.eu/transparency/documents-register/detail?ref=C(2018)5119&lang=en).

> *Article 29*
> *Recovery procedure and default interest applicable*
>
> 1. If  the  Member  State  upon  which  the  Court  of  Justice  has  imposed  a  lump  sum  or  penalty  payment  has  not  effected
>    payment  by  the  deadline  specified  in  the  letter  requesting
>    payment, the accounting officer shall immediately send a letter of
>    formal  notice,  asking  it  to  pay  the  amount  owed  within
>    fifteen  calendar  days,  plus  default  interest at the rate referred
>    to in Article 9.
> 2. If  payment  has  still  not  been  made  on
>    expiry  of  the  fifteen  calendar  days  following  receipt  of  the
>    letter  of  formal  notice  by  the  Member  State,  the  accounting
>    officer   shall  recover  the  amount  by  offsetting  in  accordance
>    with  the  procedure  set  out  in  Article 31 after having informed
>    the authorising officer responsible and having given  the indebted
>    Member State the opportunity to submit comments.

> *Article 31*
> *Offsetting*
> In  the  circumstances  provided  for  in
> Article  29(2),  the  total  amount  of  the  lump  sum  or  penalty
> payment  imposed  by  the  Court  of  Justice,  plus  interest,  shall
> be  deducted  from  payments due to the Member State.

However, paragraph 2 of Article 30 of that Commission Decision grants the Commission the ability to determine the date on which Poland took measures to comply with the Court's judgement, and to cancel any penalty payments owed from that date forward:-

> In the case of penalty payments, it is for the Commission to determine
> the date on which the Member State took measures to comply with the
> Court’s judgment against it for failure to perform its obligations and
> immediately put an end to the recovery procedure.
>
> Any surplus penalty
> payments collected after that date shall be repaid to the Member
> State, and the recovery orders in question shall be amended or
> cancelled. In accordance with Article 116(5) of the Financial
> Regulation, surplus penalty payments collected shall be repaid without
> interest.

As such, a decision by the European Commission could *technically* determine that Poland began to take measures to comply with the judgement on September 21st, 2021, and cancel all subsequent penalty payments. Hungary acting alone, however, could not veto the decision to collect the payments by offsetting against subsidies.